# Remove category Group Name from Low Search select

Tags: low-search

As per the title. I have categories set up like this example:

Group Name: Amps
Children: Pre > Power > Integrated

Then using:

```
   <select name="category:Amps[]">
  {exp:channel:categories channel="sound" style="linear" category_group="2"}
    <option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
  {/exp:channel:categories}
   </select>
```

How do you exclude the Group Name and just bring back the children in the rendered select dropdown? Otherwise on submit it will bring back ALL results if nothing is selected.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GWcode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation) instead, you do get much more control over the category output.

```
   <select name="category:Amps[]">
  {exp:gwcode_categories channel="sound" depth="2" show_empty="no"}
    <option value="{cat_id}">{cat_name}</option>
  {/exp:gwcode_categories}
   </select>
```

^ This is a mock up, not actual code.